# C++/Windows Multi threaded synchronization/Data Sharing

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, synchronization

My requirement is that a single frame of data is to be processed by two methods in parallel (they need to be parallel because they are which are computationally demanding).

Based on the result of either of the threads, the other need to be stopped.
That is if method 1 returns TRUE first, method 2 should be stopped.
If method 1 returns FALSE first, method 2 should not be stopped.

Similarly, if method 2 returns TRUE first, method 1 should be stopped.
If method 2 returns FALSE first, method 1 should not be stopped.

Please note that method 1 and method 2 are library calls (black box) and I don't have access to their internals. All I know is that they are computationally intense.
How can I implement it in C++/Windows? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter if you use [plain Windows threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`std::thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920601.aspx), [Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx), or whatever library you prefer, you're still not going to achieve what you want given the details you provided in your question.

While you can certainly figure out when the first thread/task is finished (e.g. @j-w's answer), you cannot really stop the other task *gracefully* without telling your "blackbox library function" to stop (unless it provides a ways for explicit early cancellation). You didn't indicate the blackbox function can be told to cancel midway, so I'm assuming it is not.

You cannot simply kill the thread/task since this would create resource leaks and maybe even other nasty stuff such as dealocks, etc. depending on what your blackbox function does.

So, you could go with something like `when_any`, or other synchronization/signaling primitives, and just let the other thread/task continue to run even though you don't need the result, "un-blackbox" your library functions and add cancellation support, or forget about it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the concurrency runtime.
Specifically the *task* namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx) and the *when_any* function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh749973.aspx).
*concurrency::when_any* will create a task that completes when any of the input tasks complete.